# C++ sugar syntax for if (!result) return false;

Tags: c++, syntactic-sugar

When refactoring some code, I often encounter this :

```
bool highLevelFunc foo()
{
  // ...
  bool result = LesserLevelFunc();
    if (!result) return false;
  // ... Keep having fun if we didn't return
}
```

Is there any way to make this a little more sexy and less verbose ? Without any overhead or pitfall of course.

I can think of a macro

```
#define FORWARD_IF_FALSE(r) if (!r) return r;

bool highLevelFunc foo()
{
  // ...
  FORWARD_IF_FALSE(LesserLevelFunc());
  // ...
}
```

Anything better, i.e without preprocessor macro?

Comment: @MitchWheat He only wants to return out of the function if it fails at that point. If not false, he wants to continue.

Comment: @MitchWheat a true condition would not "return" in the original example.

Comment: hard to say without seeing more code...

Comment: @MitchWheat I thought the three dots would be meaningful. Of course I want to return only if the subfunction failed :)

Comment: Your `FORWARD_IF_FALSE` computes twice `LesserLevelFunc` (when false). And it misses parenthesis around `r`.

Comment: Exceptions? Not particularly sexy (at least by my standards), but certainly less verbose in places that don't handle them.

Comment: You can certainly make it less verbose (e.g. `if (!LesserLevelFunc()) return false;` or even `if (LesserLevelFunc()) { // other_stuff; return true; } return false;` - unless you really need to capture the function return value for something else. Code that is more "sexy" is a highly subjective analysis and probably doesn't have a meaningful answer. Honestly, I would never refer to code as "sexy" anyway... Guess I just don't roll that way...

Comment: Remember, placing code on one line or using macros does not speed up execution and the impact on build is negligible.  Readability is more important especially for peer reviews and team code inspections.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To me, "readable" code is sexy. I find the original code more readable than your proposal, since the original uses standard C++ syntax and the latter uses a macro which I'd have to go and look up.

If you want to be more explicit, you could say `if (result == false)` (or better yet, `if (false == result)` to prevent a possible assignment-as-comparison bug) but understanding the `!` operator is a fairly reasonable expectation in my opinion.

That said, there is no reason to assign the return value to a temporary variable; you could just as easily say:

```
if (!LesserLevelFunc()) return false;
```

This is quite readable to me.

**EDIT**: You could also consider using exceptions instead of return values to communicate failure. If `LesserLevelFunc()` threw an exception, you would not need to write any special code in `highLevelFunc()` to check for success. The exception would propagate up through the caller to the nearest matching `catch` block.

Comment: Yeah well the online check/return is the way to go. I agree with exceptions but it's not necessarly always practical to use.

Answer (score 6):

Because you might be continuing if `LesserLevelFunc` returns true, I suggest keeping it pretty close to how it is now:

```
if (!LesserLevelFunc())
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all introducing the macro you are making the code unsafe. Moreover your macro is invalid.

The expression after the negation operator shall be enclosed in parentheses.

```
#define FORWARD_IF_FALSE(r) if (!( r ) ) return r;
```

Secondly the macro calls r twice. Sometimes two calls of a function is not equivalent to one call of the same function. For example the function can have some side effects or internal flags that are switched on/off in each call of the function.

So I would keep the code as is without introducing the macro because the macro does not equivalent to the symantic of the original code.